# Update terraform resource after provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

so I recently asked a question about [how to provision instances that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64903771/3137789). The answer I got was that I could instantiate the 3 instances, then have a `null resource` with a `remote-exec` provisioner that would update each instances.

It works great, except that in order to work my instances need to be configured to allow ssh. And since they are in a private subnet, I first need to allow ssh in a public instance that will then bootstrap my 3 instances. This bootstrap operation requires allowing ssh on 4 instances that really don't need to once the bootstrap is complete. This is not that bad, as I can still restrict the traffic to known ip/subnet, but I still thought it was worth asking if there was some ways to avoid that problem.

Can I update the security group of running instances in a single terraform plan? Example: Instantiate 3 instances with security_group X, provision them through ssh, then update the instances with security_group Y, thus disallowing ssh. If so, how? If not, are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you replace the ssh with `run command`? Its a proper way of doing such things and it does not require any internet connectivity, as long as your instances can be managed by ssm.

Comment: I have never used ssm so it's a bit new to me, but reading quickly about it it does appear to be something that would work. If I understand correctly, I'd replace the `remote-exec` with a `local-exec` and then use the aws-cli to directly bootstrap the instances? If so, I think that'd be perfect for my use case!

Comment: Yes, as terraform does not support run-command. Alternatively you can invoke it through lambda using `aws_lambda_invocation` to keep everything at aws.

Comment: Thanks again for your help :) I'll test those 2 options tomorrow but I'm pretty confident they will work! I'll keep you updated

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer with more info.

Comment: Of course, I'd like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Instead of `ssh`, you could use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html):

> AWS Systems Manager Run Command lets you **remotely** and securely manage the configuration of your managed instances.  Run Command enables you to **automate common administrative tasks** and perform ad hoc configuration changes at scale.

This would require making your instances to be recognized by AWS Systems Manager (SSM) which requires three things:

- network connectivity to SSM service. Since your instances are in private subnet, they either have to connect to the SSM service using NAT gateway or [VPC interface endpoints for SSM](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/).
- SSM Agent installed and running. This is usually not an issue as most offical AMI on AWS already have it setup.
- Instance role with  `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` AWS managed policy.

Since run-command is [not supported by terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8075), you either have to use `local-exec` to run the command through AWS CLI, or through lambda function using [aws_lambda_invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation).